# dictionary contains only single element

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I create a dictionary with features and styles by this:

```
featureStyles = { };
myList.forEach((f) => featureStyles[f] = myStyle);
```

`myList` is an array of features having an `id`.

However when I inspect that within my debugger I get only a single element:

[image: JavaScript Dictionary with complex key]

When instead of using the feytures as keys I chose to use the features `id` I get a key-value-map as seen in the image:

[image: JavaScript Dictionary with string key]

Can´t I use objects as keys here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an object as an object key, it will be converted to string so each object will correspond to the `[object Object]`, all keys will be the same, so you are always overriding the previous key value.

You can use `WeakMap` or `Map` instead:

```
var featureStyles = new WeakMap();
// var featureStyles = new Map();

myList.forEach((f) => featureStyles.set(f, myStyle));
```

Comment: Ah, didn´t know each object is converted to string. Thank you.